# How I can turn off jsFiddle shortcuts keyboard?

Tags: jsfiddle

How I can turn off in jsFiddle shortcuts keyboard?
Because I have a little problem ... When I write in any panel and I use Polish characters, then it starts a keyboard shortcut, so I can not write Polish charactersthat, this is very annoying :/

Comment: You might try creating the text in another editor and then copying it into jsFiddle...